# How to use auto layout to create a gap between objects

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, swift4, nslayoutconstraint

My code features UITextField and UITableView. I want my code to use AutoLayout to create a small gap between the textfield and the tableview. Right now the position of the code works well if its in iPhone mode but if it is in iPad the textfield is printed over the tableview. You can see what I am dealing with in the photo below:

```
hitsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)
hitsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 150)
hitsLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
hitsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)

theScores.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 300)
theScores.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
theScores.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
theScores.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Is hitsLabel your textfield?

Comment: Yes it is that is the textfield

Comment: You center the textfield vertically in the view and don't seem to have any constraints set up between the tableview and the textfield, so of course it's going to displayed on top of the tableview. If you want the textfield above the table, you need to create a constraint between the bottom of the textfield and the top of the tableview.

Comment: You right that is what I was thinking but I dont know how to code that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
hitsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant : 100),
hitsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
hitsLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
hitsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
theScores.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hitsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 100),
theScores.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
theScores.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
theScores.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
```

This will place the textfield 100 pixels fromt the top of the view, and then the top of the tableView will be 100 pixels from the bottom of the textfield.

I would suggest adding constraints for the left side of the textfield as well